# socket.io keeping track of number of clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In Socket.io for Node, I am a little confused how the number of clients are being tracked.  In the demo offered by Socket.io, they have a global variable numUsers in their server.js and when a new client connects, client.js communicates with server.js and numUsers increments.  However, how does numUsers keep track of the number of clients, even though its value is not stored in a database?  When every unique user goes on the website, are the socket connections directed to one server, where they all can see the value of numUsers, instead of numUsers being set to 0 for every user going to the website?  Thank you.

Comment: "When every unique user goes on the website, are the socket connections directed to one server" < yes.

Comment: But the fact that the connections are directed to one server is not true of generally accessing a website correct?  It's more like every user has an "instance" of the server working in the backend?

Comment: It is. Node runs the server itself so every client "has" just one single instance of the server. You could have one client set a variable and have another access it.

Comment: Sorry for keep commenting, but so does that mean Node lacks security because according to what you say, one client could, say, create a session and another client could just alter that?  Thanks!

Comment: `session`, if you mean [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session), you'll find aren't insecure.

Comment: Also clients can only access things which you allow them. If you allow them access to a global variable sure they'll share the same space. You can also "tie" things to particular client if you want only them to be accessing it ("session").

Comment: node.js has one instance for all clients.  Session data is keyed off a client cookie so one client cannot access session data from another client.  It appears you need to learn more about how node.js works.  It is not the type of web server that spawns a new process for every connection.  There is one process only that serves all requests.  Node.js can be clustered, but that is only to increase scalability - the basic models stays the same.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm still learnin'.  Thanks for the helpful info!